# How to create a 'keywords' table from a column's values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with 8 million+ rows in it. It stores jobs and their characteristics. There is a column in it that holds job titles. I am planning to create a keyword table based on the job titles from that column, so that later the keyword table can be used to implement an auto-complete field on the client side.

For example, if the job title is `The Java programmer`, then I want to store `Java` and `programmer`. I want to eliminate all special characters, get rid of some words like `a` and `the` and break the string on space. Can you please advise me on what my approach should be? From where should I start? Is this even the right way of creating a table to store keywords?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To query the Title column you may like to investigate [Full Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx).

To create the autocomplete list you could [split the Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string) on space character and remove the small words, which you would keep in a separate pre-defined list, often called a "[stop list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)."